# No Query Studio in AppExchange

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange

(Tag suggestions welcome)

I have access to SFMC for a client. With this clients SFMC, someone has installed 'Query Studio' app:

[image]

For another client, I wanted to use this app. I went to 'AppExchange' and did a search for 'Query Studio' but see no results:

[image]

(I also noticed that when taken to AppExchange I am no longer logged in to SFMC in this tab)

How can I install Query Explorer with the new client like I have with the initial client who has Query Explorer installed?

Comment: It seems that the listing in AppExchange is private (explains why it won't display on search). Can you try this https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FP3yFUAT ?

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much. How did you know this?! I was unaware of private apps. By the way, it say's it's already installed, it just doesn't appear in the drop down menu under AppExchange :/

Comment: Hey Doug, no worries, actually I did not know about this app, only about not listed apps. I did a Google search and some blogs pointed to this. If this is installed but not showing, it is probably a permission issue, you should be able to grant permission to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing it from the Appexchange, Go to Setup -> Installed Packages -> Query Studio. Under the 'License' tab, select the business unit and select the user(s) as needed.

After setting it up, if your users still don't see the app then suggest they refresh the page or try logging in again.